# Vuejs: How to use vue-email-editor?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to integrate `vue-email-editor` into my source. I followed the instructions but still can't integrate `vue-email-editor`. And here is how I do it and the error I'm getting:

Step 1: `npm install vue-email-editor --save`

Step 2: In **App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="bar">
        <h1>Vue Email Editor (Demo)</h1>

        <button v-on:click="saveDesign">Save Design</button>
        <button v-on:click="exportHtml">Export HTML</button>
      </div>

      <EmailEditor
        :appearance="appearance"
        :min-height="minHeight"
        :project-id="projectId"
        :locale="locale"
        :tools="tools"
        :options="options"
        ref="emailEditor"
        v-on:load="editorLoaded"
        v-on:ready="editorReady"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { EmailEditor } from 'vue-email-editor';

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      EmailEditor,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        minHeight: '1000px',
        locale: 'en',
        projectId: 0, // replace with your project id
        tools: {
          // disable image tool
          image: {
            enabled: false,
          },
        },
        options: {},
        appearance: {
          theme: 'dark',
          panels: {
            tools: {
              dock: 'right',
            },
          },
        },
      };
    },
    methods: {
      // called when the editor is created
      editorLoaded() {
        console.log('editorLoaded');
        // Pass your template JSON here
        // this.$refs.emailEditor.editor.loadDesign({});
      },
      // called when the editor has finished loading
      editorReady() {
        console.log('editorReady');
      },
      saveDesign() {
        this.$refs.emailEditor.editor.saveDesign((design) => {
          console.log('saveDesign', design);
        });
      },
      exportHtml() {
        this.$refs.emailEditor.editor.exportHtml((data) => {
          console.log('exportHtml', data);
        });
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

And then I run source and get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_modules__[moduleId] is not a function
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=ee06f5f7860fd239b953:166893:41)
    at app.js?id=ee06f5f7860fd239b953:186888:68
    at app.js?id=ee06f5f7860fd239b953:187073:2
    at ./node_modules/vue-email-editor/dist/vue-email-editor.common.js (app.js?id=ee06f5f7860fd239b953:187075:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=ee06f5f7860fd239b953:64:30)
    at ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./frontend/src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js?id=ee06f5f7860fd239b953:117639:74)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=ee06f5f7860fd239b953:64:30)
    at ./frontend/src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js?id=ee06f5f7860fd239b953:110481:194)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js?id=ee06f5f7860fd239b953:64:30)
    at ./frontend/src/App.vue (app.js?id=ee06f5f7860fd239b953:110445:91)
```

Reference links : https://github.com/unlayer/vue-email-editor

I have searched a lot but there is not a solution that helps me to fix this error. If anyone has successfully integrated, please give me a solution to fix the above error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is also reported [here](https://github.com/unlayer/vue-email-editor/issues/73), and it says to downgrade the version to `1.0.0` to make it workable.

Here is the [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-2-playground-forked-dgdvn4?file=/package.json) of `vue-email-editor` with `version 1.0.0`.

*(I could not create snippet because CDN of this library is not available.)*

Comment: Thank you for sharing with me. I did it your way, I downgraded `"vue-email-editor": "1.0.0"` but still got the above error. I still have no way to fix it :))

Comment: Can you reproduce it in the codesanbox?

Comment: I just integrated this in place of `vue-email-editor`. Link : https://github.com/yakoue/vue-email-builder. I have successfully integrated. But there is a `template or render function not defined` error that I cannot fix. Can you take a look at it for me? Thank you. CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-pond-s5m022?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question of it otherwise it will be two questions in the comments. I am also looking into your code.

Comment: Yes. I will create a new question. And I will send you the link as soon as I finish creating the question

Comment: I think you should not use this package. Because this issue is already reported here and no one respond. This seems to be the package's issue itself. See here- https://github.com/yakoue/vue-email-builder/issues/1

Comment: Thank you. So can you recommend me a similar email-editor. So I can integrate it into my vue tool? Actually I'm not expert in vuejs so it's very difficult.

Comment: The previous one was a popular one. Not sure why it didn't work because it worked for me. give a try to `vue-email-editor version` 0.9.0.

Comment: I reverted back to `vue-email-editor`. Initially installed it as `2.0.0`, I downgraded to `1.0.0` and `0.9.0` respectively but still got `TypeError: __webpack_modules__[moduleId] is not a function`.. I don't know what to do now :(

Comment: Can you check the code sandbox link, I mentioned in the answer? Maybe you can provide your code details and how are you using it there and then I can debug that.

Comment: I have seen the code you demo on the sandbox. It actually ran. Now my tool is a huge tool of the company. Now I don't know how to share the most details with you. I will try to share the most details. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello. Sorry to bother you. But can you help me see this part? Thank you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75444629/mongodb-how-to-update-an-item-in-an-array-using-laravel